# Change LINQ To SQL connection string while running the application

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, connection-string

I have a VB.NET application that used LINQ To SQL. Right now, I am using a single server and it is working properly.

My problem right now is that my application will be used in another branch and with another server. I have to make the application able to change the connection string according to their server IP.

My project's connection string is in another dll called DatabaseCLS.dll.

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you have the source for DatabaseCLS? What connection string is in the .config file? Is it hardcoded in that DatabaseCLS assembly?

Comment: Forgot to mention, it is a desktop application. And, yes, I have the source for the DatabaseCLS, it is in the same solution but in a different project. No, it is not hardcoded. I used the property tab to select the connection in the .dbml file.

Answer (score 0):

If the first application correctly stores its connection string in a web.config or app.config file then you just need to add the same connection string name to your new projects web or app config.

Inside DatabaseCLS:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseCLSConnectionString" connectionString="server1" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Inside your new app:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseCLSConnectionString" connectionString="server1" />
</connectionStrings>
```